# Why a DIV is not valid within ASP tag in this code?

Tags: asp.net, css, .net-3.5, html

Below is the code of my Web Content Form. The DIV inside ASP tag shows green underline and also the text that is written in DIV tag is not visible on the Content Page.

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Presentation_Layer/Pages/home.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="default.aspx.cs" Inherits="live1._default" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" runat="server">
        <asp:Label ID="lblWelcomeMessage" runat="server" ForeColor="Black">
            <div id="divProfile"> 
                This is a test.
            </div>
        </asp:Label>
</asp:Content>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`<asp:Label runat="server"/>` renders as `span` tag on browser.

You cannot nest a block level element inside of an `inline` element. `label` and `span`
are `inline` elements, `DIV` is block level.

Comment: Thanks. Even after that the text is not visible and the green underline is there.

Comment: after what? what did you change?

Comment: @RPK even what I said above the text should be appeared. Do you have Firebug? Inspect it with Firebug. Do you have a style defined for divProfile? If yes inspect it with Firebug.

Comment: @Amr: I removed the label tag.

Answer (score 0):

Ramiz's answer is correct.  If you're looking for solutions, here are a few options:

`<asp:Panel>` renders a `<div>`.  The id won't be easily guessable, but you can set the CssClass if you need to access it using client-side script.

Another option is that you can just do this: `<div id="divProfile" runat="server">` if you want to have access to it within your codebehind.  If you need to access this with client-side script, you just set the class attribute, not the CssClass attribute.

Comment: I did all this, but why the text is not visible on the master page.

Comment: I see that your ContentPlaceHolderID="head".  Is that ContentPlaceHolder within the <head> or <body> of your MasterPage?